# How to add a slide toggle button to every cell in tabulator column

Tags: javascript, uitableview, user-interface, angular-material, tabulator

I am trying to add  to every cell in a column in tabulator table. I need to associate on click() function with this slide toggle button. How to do add angular toggle switch for every cell in a column in tabulator?

[image: I want the table to have the slide toggle button as shown in the image.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont use angular, but I have my own slide toggles and just use the formatter "html". So I would presume you can get the code/object to insert as you desire

https://jsfiddle.net/o5whLz4j/

```
new Tabulator("#tabulator", {
    data:[ {
            "one": '<input id="oneone" type="checkbox" class="switch"><label id="oneonelabel" for="oneone">One</label>',
            "two": "1",
        },{
            "one": '<input id="onetwo" type="checkbox" class="switch"><label id="onetwolabel" for="onetwo">Two</label>',
            "two": "2",
        },{
            "one": '<input id="onethree" type="checkbox" class="switch"><label id="onethreelabel" for="onethree">Three</label>',
            "two": "3",
        },
    ],
    columns: [{
            title: "One",
            field: "one",
            formatter: "html",
        },
        {
            title: "Two",
            field: "two",
        },                  
    ],
});
```